# I feel like there is something wrong with my command prompt. I would like to open files in terminal and fix the problem

Tags: command-line, macos

I'm learning python on Linkedin Learning. I downloaded exercise files from the website. In the tutorial, we are meant to write the following in terminal

```
$cd Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01
```

Now, you should note that my terminal is slightly different, instead of starting with '$cd' on the command line, it starts with

```
Zoher@Aatikas-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I did make myself an admin on my sisters computer (she gave hers to me), if that helps.

Anyhow, I would like help.
Also, my exercise files are in the correct place just to clarify. When I do enter the command like the tutorial suggests, I get this response

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /users/zoher/desktop/exercise
```

What is wrong and what is the solution?

Comment: Upper case and lower case letters are not the same. The response complains about lower case desktop and exercise, type Desktop and ExerciseFiles instead.

Comment: You prompt string likely looks different because your terminal is using a different interactive *shell* (`zsh` instead of `bash`)

Comment: I typed this in: $ cd /Users Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01
It looked like this: Zoher@Aatikas-MacBook-Air ~ % $ cd /Users Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01
I got this in response:zsh: command not found: $

Every file does exist in the correct place

Maybe it's that my terminal is using a different interactive shell as steel driver says. I don't know what that means. But, how do I get to bash instead of zsh.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are typing `/Users ...`.  From your `... % ` prompt, type `cd Descktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01`.  In the example given to you `$` is not part of the command, but just the prompt.

Comment: @Stewart because I gave the (bad) advice of typing the full path (in a deleted comment).

Answer (score 1):

The dollar sign `$` and the percentage sign `%` are part of the prompt. [Here are some examples](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Explanations/Shell_Prompt#Appearance_of_the_prompt):

> The shell prompt normally ends in a $ sign. For simplicity, the
> examples in this book use a shell prompt like this:
>
> ```
> $
> ```
>
> Some older shell prompts end in % instead:
>
> ```
> %
> ```
>
> The C shell sometimes uses > instead:
>
> ```
> >
> ```

You will find many examples where the commands shown are "prefixed" by a dollar sign `$`, meaning that the command should be run in a shell (terminal).

So when you find such examples, the command to be issued is *what follows* the prompt.

In your case the command is

```bsh
cd Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01
```

So the complete picture would be

```bsh
Zoher@Aatikas-MacBook-Air ~ % cd Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01
```

This is not all. [You can use, and should use the autocomplete feature of the shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion).